# Unnamed timer thread doesn't execute

Tags: c#, multithreading

Wondering if someone can answer something that has stumped me.

I have a Timer that sets a variable to let some other threads know when to stop execution (the length is hard coded for this example)

```
Timer endProcessingThread = new Timer(x => _endOfProcessingTimeHasElapsed = true, null, 10000, 0);
```

I don't ever join on the thread or use the timers variable name for anything so I 'cleaned' it up to say:

```
new Timer(x => _endOfProcessingTimeHasElapsed = true, null, 10000, 0);
```

This compiles fine but the thread never executes.

Anyone know why?

Comment: I assume the first (named) timer does work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: `Timer` is `IDisposable`, so that you *should* use the timer’s variable name, at least to dispose it properly.

And: Since you do not keep any reference to the created instance, it is eligible for garbage collection. And since the internals of the Timer use a finalizer, the finalizer gets called and the timer gets deleted before it had a chance to fire. (Note that just *keeping* a reference in a named local variable as in your first case is not enough, the compiler might notice the variable is not used at all and garbage collect the instance anyway.)

Solution: Keep the reference and call `Dispose()` as soon as you finished using it.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the Timer is going out of scope and being GCed before the 10 seconds are up. From MSDN:

> As long as you are using a Timer, you must keep a reference to it. As with any managed object, a Timer is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected.

The solution is to keep that reference at whatever code level will still be around in 10 seconds (or whenever) by assigning it to some class or form property/field.

Answer (score 2):

> This compiles fine but the thread never executes.

The anonymous Timer is possibly cleaned up by the Garbage collector before it triggers.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477351/in-c-where-should-i-keep-my-timers-reference).

Answer (score 1):

It could be that since you never hold a reference to the object you create, it either gets optimized away immediately (no lvalue) or it simply get GC'd and never executes.

FWIW doesn't that class implement IDisposable?  If so, you should be using a `using` statement or calling dispose.